# Sqoop free form query not working

Tags: sqoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Below is the query which I am trying in Cloudera quick start VM

> sqoop import --username training --password training --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre --target-dir /sample --split-by accounts.acct_num --query 'select accounts.first_name FROM accounts JOIN accountdevice ON (accounts.acct_num = accountdevice.account_id) WHERE $CONDITIONS'
>   kquote

Below are the table structure of the two tables used in query

```
mysql> describe accounts;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| acct_num       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| acct_create_dt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| acct_close_dt  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| address        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| zipcode        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone_number   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modified       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> describe accountdevice;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_id        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| device_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| activation_date   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_device_id | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am getting the below exception

```
SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't1.acct_num' in 'field list'
16/10/15 13:48:12 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't1.acct_num' in 'field list'
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: please keep --split-by accounts.acct_num  after --query and try once , like --query 'select accounts.first_name FROM accounts JOIN accountdevice ON (accounts.acct_num = accountdevice.account_id) WHERE $CONDITIONS' --split-by accounts.acct_num

Comment: Below is the error I am getting after following above mentioned advice.

MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't1.acct_num' in 'field list'
16/10/15 23:51:31 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't1.acct_num' in 'field list'

Comment: add -`-verbose` in the end of the query and share console logs.

Comment: it worked when I added column which I was using in split-by in select statement in free-form query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

Firstly sqoop will fetch metadata (column details) from RDBMS based on your query.

Using query:

```
select accounts.first_name FROM accounts JOIN accountdevice
 ON (accounts.acct_num = accountdevice.account_id) WHERE 1 = 0
```

*you see `$CONDITIINS` is replaced with **1 = 0** to fetch metadata.*

Now your query will return only 1 column `first_name` and you are splitting on `acct_num` which is not queried from RDBMS table. That's why you are getting **Unknown column** error.

So make sure you SELECT split by column too in your SQL query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation.